# View management with Ember.StateManager (and not Ember.Router)

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to user Ember to create an 'informational sign' type of application; The data displayed will be updated on a regular basis, but there is no user input or interaction. The application is configured and initialized based on URL parameters provided by an administrator. The layout and content of the application will change depending on the data in the feed the application is monitoring.

Ember.Router seems like overkill for this task because I don't need/can't have URL-based routes mapped to application state. Ember.StateManager seems perfect because it allows me to programmatically transition between states depending only on conditions met within the logic of my application, ignoring the current URL. The deprecated Ember.ViewState seems like it was the way to manage views when using Ember.StateManger.

What is the current best practice for managing views in the DOM with Ember.StateManger?

Is there a way to do what I'm describing with Ember.Router instead?

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: "The layout and content of the application will change depending on the data in the feed the application is monitoring." Can you give an example scenario?

Comment: Sure. The sign will be displaying bus arrival information for a bus stop. Under normal circumstances, there will be a main list of buses that are headed towards the stop. If the application receives data indicating there is a service advisory in effect on the bus route, the application will switch to a two column layout where the bus arrivals are shown on one side and a list of service advisories are displayed on the other side. I'd imagine these two conditions (no current advisories and advisories in effect) could be represented by two different application states in Ember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your primary explanation, I feel that you dont need any states at the moment. You need diferent application stated defined when application needs different behaviour in those states. Looks like your application behaviour is not changing but just view.

So you can just use some handlebars condition helpers to make this work along with some derived attribute in your controller indicating whether there is any current advisory.

```
{{#view App.myView}}
  {{#if hasAdvisory}}
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="col1">
        {{#each bus}}
          //bus details
        {{/each}}
      </div>
      <div class="col2">
        //advisory details
      </div>
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <div class="col-1">
      <div class="col">
        {{#each bus}}
          //bus details
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
{{/view}}
```

Please explain more like if you just need this or do you plan any different application behaviours when you have advisory and when you dont have.

Comment: Your description of when states are needed is really helpful. That makes sense to me. I'll try this out. Seems pretty simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the same techniques used to manage views and controllers in `Ember.Router`-based apps can be used with `Ember.StateManager`. Specifically, using outlets with `Em.Controller#connectController` is an excellent way to switch views that is independent of state management.